PATH undefined in workshop latex
I install texlive (2024) on termux (linux) with pkg install texlive-installer and it's work fine (in the terminal), but I need a tex editor therefore I install visual studio code (code-oss) and install latex workshop extension but when I run my .tex file from vscode I see this error:
    [00:26:32.105][Build] env: {}
[00:26:32.106][Build] root: %WS1%/test.tex
[00:26:32.109][Build] cwd: %WS1%
[00:26:32.164][Build] LaTeX build process spawned with PID undefined.
[00:26:32.172][Build] LaTeX fatal error on PID undefined. Error: spawn latexmk ENOENT
[00:26:32.186]Error: spawn latexmk ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[00:26:32.189][Build] Does the executable exist? $PATH: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.local/bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.local/bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/man/man1/latex.1.gz:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/texlive:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/texlive/latex:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/texlive/latexmk:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/texlive, $Path: undefined, $SHELL: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/zsh

I found lots of same topics but the instructions not work for me...
(I'm new to the latex and linux)
How can I solve this error?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Well, what did you find? Can you tell us the question, and which instructions did you follow? "Did not work" is not very clear, can you please describe what happens?

When you say working in terminal, does latexmk work from terminal? Or just *latex?

latexmk Work fine

@Mensch I search this Error and find some topics says add the path to the path variable for Latex or latexmk and Change the permission of Latex directory, and error still remains

that PATH does not look right at all. why do you have files in it? and why is it reporting $Path? how exactly did you alter the PATH variable? you should not have to change any permissions in a typical case. adjusting PATH and INFOPATH is generally sufficient (and you can do without the second). but if PATH is wrong, that would affect cli usage, too. what does which latexmk; echo $PATH return?

TeX and LaTex files are plain text, so you can use any editor you like. Using one with syntax highlighting helps, but is not essential. There are a number of editors which can be used for LaTeX code, many of which are available from Linux package managers. You also don't need to have the editor compile your document, you can do that for yourself from the terminal with the command pdflatex documentname.tex or lualatex documentname.tex. If one of those works, the problem is with the latex workshop extension of VS-Code. But try to get it working on the command line first.

@cfr thanks I also added before latexmk: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/texlive/latexmk
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/texlive/latexmk:/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.local/bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/texlive

@enkorvaks Thank you very much, this extension open the pdf file in a side bar mode for this I wants to use it & I think the vscode environment is be more user-friendly, but now I reluctance use texEditor for LaTeX & it's work fine!

/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/texlive/latexmk shouldn't be a component of your PATH. and you haven't said how you altered PATH etc. it also isn't clear what you're using in 'texEditor': latexmk? pdflatex? something else?

@cfr I added this when I saw in a thread that adding this value (latexmk directory) solves the problem, TexStudio I use it now...

is that really a directory? not the executable? what does which latexmk return?
